# eclipse wizard performFinish slowness

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, wizard

I am creating an Eclipse wizard... I am overriding the method

```
 public boolean performFinish()
```

Inside the method, I want there to be a progress monitor... So I am doing the following:

```
IRunnableWithProgress op = new IRunnableWithProgress() {
        public void run(IProgressMonitor mainMonitor) throws InvocationTargetException {
//do stuff
        }
};
```

I have ran the wizard in debug and have found that it is not my code that is making it run slow. I can simply print out something with the monitor and it still takes a little while for the performFinish to be kicked off. Is there something I am missing with performFinish? Has anyone else seen this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this.

You would normally use the progress bar built in to the wizard like this:

```
getContainer().run(true, true, runnableWithProgress);
```

in the performFinish.

You wizard should call

```
setNeedsProgressMonitor(true);
```

in its constructor to enable the wizard progress monitor.